# Why doesn't UnderscoreJS's _.extend() method copy AngularJS promises to the extended object?

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

Example:

```
$scope.post = Posts.get({id: id});
scope = _.extend({}, $scope);

alert($scope.post.id); // undefined
alert(scope.post.id); // exception - post is not defined
```

I feel that I'm doing something obviously wrong, but I can't figure out what.  I expected it to shallowly copy the `post` reference to the new object:

```
alert($scope.post.id); // undefined
alert(scope.post.id); // undefined
$scope.post === scope.post; // true
```

Comment: You are not really adding anything so you could just do. `scope = $scope.$new()`. Also post will be a promise right?

Comment: @PSL Thank you. I did figure that out as a solution to my usecase.  But I almost quit web development when this didn't work, so I would love to know the answer.

Comment: Yes @PSL, `post` will be a promise. I will update the question title to use the correct terminology.

Comment: Is Posts implemented with $resource or $http?

Comment: @BiserC. `Posts` is implemented with `$resource`

Answer (score 0):

This is from Angular documentation about ngResource

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick
>   since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then
>   rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering,
>   once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated
>   with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the
>   new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a
>   callback function for the action methods.

At the time when you are trying to extend the scope, your object is not fully there.
I hope that helps...

Comment: `$scope.post` is a reference, and since `_.extend(...)` performs a shallow copy of the object's properties, it should copy the reference to `scope.post`. It doesn't make a difference whether it's before or after the promise is resolved - the reference is the same.